# Конечные автоматы и символ "w"

Tags: конечные-автоматы

Если речь идет о конечном детерминированном автомате, то что обозначает символ "w" в параметрах задания языка? Т.е., если допустим, автомат принимает слова  L = { a^n b ; n=1,2,3}, то это будут цепочки ab, aab, aaab. Но что если автомат принимает слова L = {a^nbwab | w={a,b}*}, n=1,2,3} ? Зачем там символ "w", что он означает? Объясните, пожалуйста, человеческим языком.

Comment: Cудя по синтаксису, w означает одно из состояний a или b, повторяющееся 0 или более раз.

Comment: А как на практике-то это использовать? Какие там цепочки должны быть? Если смотреть на примеры, то такое ощущение, что "w" там вообще в расчет не берется. Но для чего-то же оно там стоит?

Comment: Ощущение, что это эквивалент `{ a^nb{a,b}*ab; n = 1, 2, 3 }`, но подкрепить это мне решительно нечем, слабо знаком с нотацией.

Comment: А как его использовать, если это эквивалент? Вообще в учебных материалах написано, что w - это цепочка символов. А звездочка за фигурными скобками что может означать?